# Given the coordinates of three points, how to determine if the triangle defined is equilateral, isosceles or scalene?

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

I've written the following code, but I can't make sure if it recognizes an equilateral triangle because I can't input the coordinates I need to make it (square root of 3, for example):

```
x1 = eval(input('x1: '))
y1 = eval(input('y1: '))
x2 = eval(input('x2: '))
y2 = eval(input('y2: '))
x3 = eval(input('x3: '))
y3 = eval(input('y3: '))
side1 = (abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)) ** (1/2)
side2 = (abs(x2 - x3) + abs(y2 - y3)) ** (1/2)
side3 = (abs(x3 - x1) + abs(y3 - y2)) ** (1/2)
print('side1: ', side1, 'side2: ', side2,'side3:', side3)
if side1 + side2 > side3 and side2 + side3 > side1 and side1 + side3 > side2 :
    if side1 == side2 == side3:
        print('This triangle is equilateral')
    elif side1 == side2 or side2 == side3 or side1 == side3 :
        print('This triangle is isosceles')
    else:
        print('This triangle is scalene')
else:
    print('This is not a triangle!')
```

EDIT: I've rewritten the code as follows

```
x1 = eval(input('x1: '))
y1 = eval(input('y1: '))
x2 = eval(input('x2: '))
y2 = eval(input('y2: '))
x3 = eval(input('x3: '))
y3 = eval(input('y3: '))
side1 = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2) ** (1/2)
side2 = ((x2 - x3)**2 + (y2 - y3)**2) ** (1/2)
side3 = ((x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2) ** (1/2)
print('side1: ', side1, 'side2: ', side2,'side3:', side3)
if side1 + side2 > side3 and side2 + side3 > side1 and side1 + side3 > side2 :
    if side1 == side2 == side3:
        print('This triangle is equilateral')
    elif side1 == side2 or side2 == side3 or side1 == side3 :
        print('This triangle is isosceles')
    else:
        print('This triangle is scalene')
else:
    print('This is not a triangle!')
```

Comment: Logic error - `side1 = ((abs(x1 - x2))**2 + (abs(y1 - y2))**2) ** (1/2)`

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. Are you asking if the code is good? Or are you asking how to input irrational numbers (e.g. square root of two)?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to find how to input irrational numbers, but I already solved it, Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you square the coordinate distance, you don't need **abs**.
- Your second **y** coordinate for side3 is wrong: should be **y1**)).
- Your check for legal sides should include equality: sides of 2, 2, 4
  give you straight line, but you classify it as an isosceles triangle.
- You can use the **math** package for a more readable square root.
- You can save a step or two by sorting the side lengths; this simplifies
  your comparisons.

Updated code:

```
from math import sqrt

x1 = float(raw_input('x1: '))
y1 = float(raw_input('y1: '))
x2 = float(raw_input('x2: '))
y2 = float(raw_input('y2: '))
x3 = float(raw_input('x3: '))
y3 = float(raw_input('y3: '))

side1 = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
side2 = sqrt((x2 - x3)**2 + (y2-y3)**2)
side3 = sqrt((x3 - x1)**2 + (y3-y1)**2)

# Put the sides into a list; sort them.
tri= [side1, side2, side3]
tri.sort()

if tri[0] < tri[1]+tri[2]:
    if tri[0] == tri[2]:
        print('This triangle is equilateral')
    elif tri[1] == tri[2] or tri[1] == tri[0]:
        print('This triangle is isosceles')
    else:
        print('This triangle is scalene')
else:
    print('This is not a triangle!')
```

Comment: +1 if you add the Collinearity test case! `slope of (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)==slope of (x1,y1) and (x3,y3)` ! In this case it doesn't even form a triangle. A very important test case.

Comment: Collinearity is already in the code: note the first **if** statement.  The points are collinear *iff* the longest side's measure is equal to the sum of the other two.  There's no need to compute slopes and handle 0div cases.  This code classes a collinear case as "not a triangle".

Comment: I was really sleepy when I wrote this code so I made some very dumb mistakes. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the question is really about how to enter the input. You need to wrap the input in quotes because `eval` expects string input, not number types.

The `eval` function will parse that string as Python code. Thus, you use the same square root syntax as you do in your code.

So for example, let's test an equilateral triangle. I run your (edited) script from the terminal, and enter the coordinates as strings.

```
x1: '0'
y1: '0'
x2: '2'
y2: '12**0.5'
x3: '4'
y3: '0'
('side1: ', 1.0, 'side2: ', 1.0, 'side3:', 1.0)
This triangle is equilateral
```